Is ethics anything other than hand waving and sophistry?
Philosophy deals with the universal. Even postmodernist philosophers like Derrida would agree that all texts are deconstructible, and that all meaning di(e)ffers itself etc.
Ethics, on the other hand, has nothing to do with the universal because human actions are nothing but contingent empirical facts.
There are billions of us on this planet, and there is no ethical / moral principle that would equally apply to all of us.
I also do not understand why do people ask so many questions relating to ethics on this forum because all answers are either sophistry, religious dogma or personal opinions. The idea that there is something that all 8 billion of us SHOULD be doing makes no sense to me, and yet there are so many questions asking things like "is it ethical to do X?" or "is morally justifiable do to Y?".
I agree with Schopenhauer that Kant's second critique is sophistry. Wittgenstein said in the tractatus that all propositions relating to ethics are meaningless.
Is ethics even a part of philosophy because there is nothing universal in it?

There is something that's at least ethics-adjacent that is real and concrete. "What outcomes would you prefer, if you were perfectly informed?" Certainly if you were better informed, you would be wiser and therefore want different things from what you want right now. What preferences does wisdom lead towards? You can't avoid having preferences, and your preferences may change as you learn more, and therefore this is a real question with a real answer and real relevance to your life.

informed about what? would i be wiser if i was informed about the weather in japan today? what outcomes are you talking about? what preferences are you talking about? if i start preferring strawberry iceream over pistachio or rap over rock-n-roll, that is of real relevance to my life?

(1) "Informed about what?" Informed about everything. The weather in Japan, sure, but also and more importantly the outcome of different people's lives depending on how they chose to live, and their true feelings about that. (2) "What preferences are you talking about?" Any preferences, including, sure, ice cream preferences, but more importantly preferences that are morality-adjacent. How hard do you prefer to work? How much alcohol do you prefer to drink? How do you prefer to treat the people around you? With more knowledge and wisdom your preferences on these questions may change.

'Universal'. You seem to accept that notion uncritically. I don't think there is anything that's completely objective, only whatever is the most intersubjective - shared by the most subjectivities. See: 'Is the Categorical Imperative Simply Bad Math?' https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/84498/is-the-categorical-imperative-simply-bad-math/84523#84523 on intersubjectivity as the basis for moral reasoning, through balancing mutual benefits & harms


Ethics is normative, not descriptive. Hence persons do not discover
what IS right or wrong. They determine what
SHOULD BE right or wrong within their society.
The content of the stipulations may change during the course of
time. And it may differ from society to society. As a consequence
the validity of a given ethics is much more restricted than the
universal validity of the laws of nature.

Nevertheless ethics is not totally arbitrary. Due to its function to
enable humans to live together in social groups.
This
answer from the present blog discusses to which degree the
ethics underlying the human rights is accepted by different
nations on earth.

I do not consider discussing ethical questions to be sophistry.
Just the opposite: Rational discussion in ethics is a method how
people, societies and nations can dissolve their conflicts without
violence.



regarding point 3. do you know of any examples of that ever happening in history? i don't, not a single conflict was ever resolved with ethical discussions as far as i know

@DennisKozevnikoff I consider examples the work of advisory boards for national constitutions or for the UNO declaration of human rights. But ethics is powerless when institution lack to enforce the result – that’s the problem. The International Court of Justice at The Hague gives some hope to me, see https://www.icj-cij.org/home

I'd like to point out a number of things, and suggest a few things that might change your mind, if you're interested. But, to answer your question: yes, ethics is far more than just sophistry and hand-waving. Ethics and moral philosophy are very sophisticated and nuanced at this point in the history of philosophy, and there are many ways to approach them you might not be aware of.
A) Philosophy isn't necessarily concerned with "the universal". Philosophy deals with all sorts of issues: metaphysical, ethical, moral, epistemological, axiological, and much besides. Sometimes it's concerned with very specific empirical facts, and sometimes it's concerned with the most abstract, general claims. Never think you've reached the end. In fact, if you think you've reached the end of an issue in philosophy, assume you've barely begun.
B) Derrida's philosophy is very much concerned with the history of philosophy and pertains to concepts within the Western Tradition. I'm not sure what you were getting at in referring to him, but his claims regarding texts, deconstruction, meaning, and differance largely involve his reactions to various other philosophers. Also, he famously said later in his career that "deconstruction is ethics".
C) There are plenty of candidates for universal moral or ethical principles. You may disagree with them, but stating they are "sophistry, religious dogma, or personal opinion" is not an argument. It is also patently false. There are a few broad traditions--Deontology, Utilitarianism, and Virtue Ethics--and the relations between them are considered in various different ways, and there's more besides them. Consider the following candidate for a principle and ask yourself if you seriously doubt that you consider it "sophistry, religious dogma, or personal opinion": All people are morally required to consider the effects of their actions on others.
D) I suggest you check out Aristotle, John Stuart Mill, David Hume, and Immanuel Kant on ethics and moral philosophy, if you haven't already. Start with the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy, and then go to their original works. If you're already familiar with them, I'd check out some more recent moral and ethical thinkers: GE Moore, RM Hare, Alasdair MacIntyre, Thomas Nagel, TM Scanlon, and Christine Korsgaard, to name but a few.
I wish you the best on your journey.

Philosophy in its current acedemic form does not deal with universals. Philosophy is the endeavour of creating, arranging and making the critique of concepts, which are tools who use to organise our thoughts.
Ethics is a domain, probably THE domain, where we want our thoughts to be organised. Otherwise as OP says, it's all opinions. Applying rational thoughts on moral sentiments allows us to identify established modes of evaluation and justification for actions, like Deontologism if one thinks actions should be judged based on motives, or Consequentialism if one thinks action should be judged on outcomes, or Virtue ethics if one thinks character comes before action, good character leading to good actions. Once one has identified the premises of an ethical opinion, one can benefit from the work and analysis done by previous philosophers and know the implications behind their mode of justification.
This ordering of thoughts is of litle importance on a personal level, because after all, if we lived in a vacuum, nothing bad would happen to us for acting without consistency. But we actually don't live in a vacuum. We live among other humans who expect from us a fair and predictable behavior, just as we expect from them, because it makes everyone's life easier. We discuss ethics and the organisation of our ife in common with the people around us quite a lot, and no fruitful discussion could happen if we didn't have proper ethical concepts.
Of course there is nothing that forces us to accept the premises of either Kantianism or Pragmatism, or Utilitarianism, but if we want to have a rational discussion two people who accept the same premises should reach the same conclusion, or if we reject a previously accepted premise because it became inconvenient we must reevaluate all the actions we justified by using it. Which is after all exactly the same thing as any logicaly articulated discourse.
So while it is true that ethical statements don't describe reality in the way factual statements do, and don't have the same immediate utility, they are however useful to communicate our expectations vis a vis others and justify our behavior. When Wittgenstein says moral statements in the form "one should..." are meaningless, he means no more than "those are not statements about reality". "menaningless" in Wittgenstein's work is a very specific concept with specific meaning and this should be considered carefully. He said the same about litterature and all fictional statements like "Odysseus was the king of Ithaca", yet I never heard that he advised we toss away all novels and movies.

most philosophers would not agree with how you define philosophy because it is much way more than thought organization. things like metaphysics, philosophy of history  or postmodernism have nothing to do with how human thoughts are arranged

@DennisKozevnikoff what you are saying is 1, outdated, which is why I precised "current academic form" 2, not very well though out, since metaphysics, philosophy of history and postmodernism have everything to do with "creating, arranging and making the critique of concepts". When Thomas Aquinas fills pages after pages about the nature of God and the Trinity he does nothing else. Obviously there is a bunch of topics, like Wittgenstein's concept of meaning, your grasp of is still a bit flimsy.
