Unifying property of ethical theories?
Let’s say there are different theories for what the defining properties of “ethicality” are. Some theories think in utilitarian terms and in terms of maximizing subjective goodness or badness (positive sensations, happiness, pain, suffering, etc.) Other theories may have a very different framework, where ethicality is associated with something completely different than “subjective primitives” like “good” and “bad”. For example, I think a theory of ethics could be based more on how the exercise of one’s own free will acknowledges and sanctions the reality of another’s free will.
Let’s say there are many other theories of what primitive notions are at the basis for any ethical theory; what the core categories by which we evaluate “ethicality” even are.
Is there any unifying property they share? Is there a category of “ethical theories” which may differ in many parameters but share something in common making it valid to define them all as “potential theories of ethics”?

We evaluate "ethicality" of a doctrine by its applications. There is a broader agreement on what kinds of situations ethics/morality is (ultimately) supposed to address than on primitive notions, and on whether this or that concrete issue is ethical than on any "core categories". "There is much disagreement about what, exactly, constitutes a moral theory... At the most minimal, morality is a set of norms and principles that govern our actions with respect to each other and which are taken to have a special kind of weight or authority." SEP

@Julius Hamilton What is a unifying property? All ethical theories are normative, not descriptive. They follow Hume's insight: An "Is" does not imply an "Ought".

@JoWehler - I don't think prescriptive/descriptive is at issue here. There are many prescriptions and rules that are (almost universally) accepted as having no "ethical" import or that only indirectly have "ethical" value. Driving on the right side of the road. Rules of chess. Rules of logical inference. At some point it becomes more messy: Rules of user-friendly GUI design (mostly esthetics, efficiency, but partially ethical sometimes). Etc...

@mudskipper I agree: All moral systems are normative, but not all normative systems are moral systems.

See 'Is the Categorical Imperative Simply Bad Math? :)' https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/84498/is-the-categorical-imperative-simply-bad-math/84523#84523 I think it has to be intersubjectivity, because moral reasoning is about pursuading other. If that is not involved, actions just become about power, and game-theory dynamics

@CriglCragl - But is reasoning that important? Ethics concerns everyone, also those who are not particularly strong in "reasoning", and it needs to be integrated with feelings, attitudes, actions. -- Huck Finn helps Jim, the fugitive slave, despite "reason" telling him he'd surely go to hell for this.

@mudskipper: Yes. The Is-Ought distinction is fine, but we cannot pursuade others directly what values to hold, they result from our temperament encountering experience, from our biology & evolution. But we can pursuade people how to act on their values, what to contemplate that might shift ir reframe their experiences. That is the domain of moral philosophy & practical ethics. Moral action, yes, often unreasoned in the moment, yet resulting from our 'karma', what habits & patterns we have laid down

@CriglCragl - pursuade? ? I think you have more faith in the power of rational persuasion than I have.

@mudskipper: Rational is a bad substitute for intersubjectivity. I want to know what you would do, in my position. Cultivated, that is society. Denigrated, libertarian individuality, that builds nothing more than one person can make.

@CriglCragl - I don't know. I don't know your circumstances. I'm also not a missionary or moralist, so I rarely try to persuade anybody to do anything.

@mudskipper: Arguing things out here Socratic Method style, mutual enquiry into truth, is still about making a record that will hopefully inform others, & ally them to our views

You say:

Let’s say there are different theories for what the defining properties of “ethicality” are.

No need to suppose, ethicists use the term meta-ethical theory to label what you are describing. Given the variation in ethical theories, it's very useful to approach the topic comparatively. For instance, some meta-theories are relativistic, other realistic, and others non-cognivist.
You ask:

Is there any unifying property they share? Is there a category of “ethical theories” which may differ in many parameters but share something in common making it valid to define them all as “potential theories of ethics”?

Meta-ethical theories share the property they provide rational frameworks for dealing with ethics. If they have a common core, it could probably articulated around the notion of the evolution of morality. Human beings are not tabula rasa who can simply be molded into beings. They have a biological nature that exerts a tremendous influence on their personalities, if twin studies are believed.
As far as the contents of that shared notion, such words as altruism, self-preservation, and fairness might be included, however, the notion of both moral realism and the scientific study of morality are very controversial. The sole author I have who speaks copiously on the subject is Frans de Waal, an ethologist and primatologist. I can speak to The Bonobo and Atheist (GB) and Primates and Philosophers (GB), but he has other works like Good Natured (GB) which riff on the same theme.
A game theoretic form of naturalism has also been offered by Kenneth Binmore. It has been offered that human behavior is empirically consistent enough to be modeled. From WP:

His search for the philosophical foundations of the original position took him first to Kant's works, and then to Hume. Hume inspired Binmore to contribute to a naturalistic science of morals that seeks foundations for Rawlsian ideas about fairness norms in biological and social evolution. The result was his two-volume Game Theory and the Social Contract, an ambitious attempt to lay the foundations for a genuine science of morals using the theory of games. In Game Theory and the Social Contract Binmore proposes a naturalistic reinterpretation of John Rawls' original position that reconciles his egalitarian theory of justice with John Harsanyi's utilitarian theory. His recent Natural Justice provides a nontechnical synthesis of this work. (link mine)


Ken Binmore (e.g. in Natural Justice) proposes a naturalistic/evolutionary/game-theoretic interpretation of Rawl's original position. One acute problem that this may give more insight in is the problem of historical change of our actual moral intuitions -- for instance, it's also unimaginable to us now that people in the 19th century, before the US Civil War, actually tried to compromise on slavery.

Psychological/game-theoretic studies of the Ultimatum Game (Werner Güth, a.o.) are also in line with de Waals' studies. What is interesting there are the strong differences between observed outcomes for people in our society versus people from pre-industrial hunter-gatherer cultures. This may reflect a different concrete sense of fairness (in relation to power).

@mudskipper Thanks. Someday I may venture deeper into readings in ethics and morality. This theme about the universal nature of morality springs up from time to time.

@mudskipper Added your materials because I'm always falling back on de Waal only.

I believe you once mentioned you had been involved as negotiator in certain situations - This should make the Ultimatum Game interesting for you.

@mudskipper Bargaining units, sure. I'll save it to my books I wish I could buy list.

@mudskipper Ha! He's a Very Short Introduction author: https://www.google.com/books/edition/Game_Theory_A_Very_Short_Introduction/2poSDAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0 Small world.

I recently read the following lines:

I draw a distinction between morality and ethics. Morality is about how human relations should be in virtue of our being human and in virtue of nothing else.
Ethics, in contrast, is about what relations we should have with other people in virtue of some special relationships we have with them, such as family relations or friendship.
Morality, by its very nature, is based on the category of belonging to humanity, in the sense of belonging to the human species. The assault on humanity inflicted when humans are treated as nonhumans undermines the very project of morality, the project of constituting human relations as they should be.

(in: Avishai Margalit, On Compromise and Rotten Comprises, 2009)
By and large I agree with that, though I would not limit morality to relations with other humans. Humans may be more important. But surely,  relations we (as humans) have with other sentient creatures also fall under the domain of morality, at least in so far as sentience (the ability to feel pain) is concerned.
The core of moral sense then is recognizing and treating another human being as human being, which implies recognizing an essential equality between others and ourselves. This manifests itself both as empathy with others (or sympathy, as @TedWrigley pointed out in this answer) and in a sense of fairness (fair division of scarce resources, fair apportionement of rights and duties).
In classical Chinese philosophy the common term that more or less translates to "morality" is 仁義 rén-yì. This is a compound word consisting of 仁 rén - usually translated by itself as "benevolence", "humanity", "humaneneness" or simply "kindness" - and 義 yì - usually translated as "righteousness". This seems to reflect the same polarity of empathy/kindness and fairness (right). It's sometimes pointed out that the character 仁 consist of the radical for "human" (亻left side) and the symbol for "two" (二 on the right side); the German word "Mitmenschlichkeit" seems an appropriate translation (or the Yiddish phrase "be a Mensch").
I'm calling attention to Chinese philosophy because I think it does show that the core of morality is transcultural - even though in different cultures there are still important differences in how moral ideas were realized. (Also, what a culture expresses in its moral philosophies may very well conflict with actual institutionalized practice. Greek culture saw no problem in slavery. Christian plantation owners in the Southern US states also saw no problem. Women are hardly even mentioned in Chinese philosophy. This makes me wonder what the blind spots in our own moral sensivities and intuitions may be.)
In one of the most important Ruist (Confucianist) texts, the book of Mengzi, Mengzi (and others) also reflect on what the core of morality is, what its most important source is (is it natural or cultural?) and how moral sense can be developed. In the Gong Sun Chou I chapter, in what is probably the most important passage of the whole book, the author writes:

孟子曰：「人皆有不忍人之心。先王有不忍人之心，斯有不忍人之政矣。以不忍人之心，行不忍人之政，治天下可運之掌上。所以謂人皆有不忍人之心者，今人乍見孺子將入於井，皆有怵惕惻隱之心。非所以內交於孺子之父母也，非所以要譽於鄉黨朋友也，非惡其聲而然也。由是觀之，無惻隱之心，非人也；無羞惡之心，非人也；無辭讓之心，非人也；無是非之心，非人也。」

In D.C. Lau's translation (italics are mine):

Mencius said, "No man is devoid of a heart sensitive to the suffering of others (不忍人之心). Such a sensitive heart was possessed by the Former Kings and this manifested itself in compassionate government. With such a sensitive heart behind compassionate government, it was as easy to rule the Empire as rolling it on your palm.
"My reason for saying that no man is devoid of a heart sensitive to the suffering of others is this. Suppose a man were, all of a sudden to see a young child on the verge of falling into a well. He would certainly be moved to compassion, not because he wanted to get into the good graces of the parents, nor because he wished to win the praise of his fellow villagers or friends, nor yet because he disliked the cry of the child. From this it can be seen that whoever is devoid of the heart of compassion is not human, whoever is devoid of the heart of courtesy and modesty [deference and respect] is not human, and whoever is devoid of the heart of right and wrong is not human.

He goes on to identify what according to him are morality's four "starting points" (translated a little akwardly as 'germ' by Lau). Note that here he doesn't make a strict distinction between 'morality' and 'ethics' (as Margalit did in the initial quote) or between 'morality' and wisdom. However, in the initial passage above there does seem to be a clear notion that 'morality' goes beyond action based on special personal relationships (family, friends, or ingroup).
I've added some alternative glosses/intepretations between square brackets. Note also that the general social mores (禮 lǐ - the "rites") are also part of the picture here.

「惻隱之心，仁之端也；羞惡之心，義之端也；辭讓之心，禮之端也；是非之心，智之端也。人之有是四端也，猶其有四體也。有是四端而自謂不能者，自賊者也；謂其君不能者，賊其君者也。凡有四端於我者，知皆擴而充之矣，若火之始然，泉之始達。苟能充之，足以保四海；苟不充之，不足以事父母。」


The heart of compassion is the germ of benevolence (仁 rén); the heart of shame [shame and dislike], of dutifulness (義 yì); the heart of courtesy and modesty [deference and respect], of observance of the rites (禮 lǐ); the heart of right and wrong, of wisdom. Man has these four germs just as he has four limbs. For a man possessing these four germs to deny his own potentialities [to call himself incapable] is for him to cripple himself; for him to deny the potentialities of his prince is for him to cripple his prince. If a man is able to develop all these four germs that he possesses, it will be like a fire starting up or a spring coming through. When these are fully developed, he can tend the whole realm within the Four Seas, but if he fails to develop them, he will not be able to even serve his parents."


The necessary (if not sufficient) condition for ethical behavior is sympathy, in the sense of common feeling. An act cannot be ethical just for one person; it needs to be understood as ethical by the entire community, and seen as ethical if undertaken by any member of the community. In virtue ethics all people are encouraged to achieve their ideal selves; in consequentialist ethos all people are expected to consider the consequences of their actions; in religious ethics all people should seek to maintain tenets of the faith; in deontological ethics all people should accept ethical rules as universals… Each individual in a community understands that there's a common feeling that should be respected by every member of the community, and strives to respect it.
The reason that sympathy is not sufficient for ethicality has to do with cliques, cohorts, and other insular groups. It's perfectly possible — even common — for an insular group to develop an internal ethic that has no common feeling (sympathy) with external groups or individuals. This can lead to unethical acts against out-groups without any sense of ethical violation, so long as in-group members act ethically towards each other.
Ethics isn't difficult to understand, philosophically speaking. The difficulty lies in human tendencies to be both selfish and cliquish: to factionalize into self-serving groups. The various schools and theories we find in the field of ethics amount to various attempts to break through this factional spirit and create a universal common feeling. But it's a tough nut to crack.


Is there any unifying property [that ethical theories] share?

The obvious property they share is that they are about ethics and not say, about physics. But this is not a 'unifying' property. It merely marks out a genus of theories. It does not unify them into one theory.

Their common property is mostly that they seek to answer the question: How should human beings act? However as they come to different conclusions or use incompatible approaches there isn't much more that they agree upon.
Apparently "ethics" and "moral" both come from either Greek or Latin words for "customs" or "how people behave" (descriptive or normative) and as such are concerned with the question how people do behave, what is the right way to behave and what is good and right to begin with.
Which often come with unstated but definitely assumed premises of "what is the larger purpose of ethics" and "who decides what the purpose is".
Like a simple form ethics might come from a tyrant arguing, "Thou shall do like that, for I say so". Or you could have a certain goal in mind, then "good" is what gets you closer to that goal and bad is what moves you further away from it. Which prompts the question as to who has the right to define such a goal and morality and are you required to follow a purpose that is not your own?
So is morality just "might makes right"? Well yes, the entity holding power and being able to make laws is the one who decides what is moral (customary) and people not following those customs act criminally.
And in cases of religion god is often envisioned as powerful enough to enforce that from him-/her-/itself alone. While for the more mundane laws you do require some level of consent as the governed usually outnumber the governing entities by a large margin.
However if the consent of the governed is required than this ends up being a mixture of loads of different ideas of morality and purposes that it should accomplish and hence it seizes to be this neat set of rules that are universal, objective and self-explaining and more of an attempt to weave all the subjective ideas into a collective and objective mesh.
So often enough an unstated meta-goal of ethics, is to find customs that enable a society that doesn't fracture and descend into chaos or where people attack and kill each other. Which means that the custom of defining, enforcing, applying and whatnot of the customs is part of a matter of making, defining, enforcing, ... the customs itself.
Where again you can take different perspective, like what should the specific individual do? What should society as a whole do? Like you can argue that if >10% of people act criminal that this is a good margin, but how can the individual know that they are in the 10% or the 90%. Like the majority can assume they are in the 90% but so would the 10% ... So if everyone did someone the effect could be enormous while if only a small number of people does the same thing the effect might be negligible, though effective the individual did the same thing whether he does so as part of a majority or minority. Meaning while it could make sense to define such a limit, it's absolutely useless for the individual who can't act upon that, even if they wanted to.
Though the other way around if you focus on what the individual should or shouldn't do, you either have to massively restrict the individual to almost no freedom at all or you face the problem that from collective movement of individuals you can generate collective patterns that were not intended by the individual and cannot neatly be addressed by universal individual regulations.
So in effect something that sounds fairly simple "How should we act?", becomes really really difficult to answer.

May this note find us all ever closer to God, and His Peace.
I beg for your patient in a short tangent that may help Frame my answer with a perspective.
PS. edited, in defense of expecting of 'no references.'
'The Principal Errors of Vatican II', http://catholicapologetics.info/modernproblems/vatican2/Privatican.htm
This question would have been difficult or impossible before my Catholic conversion 6-7 years ago, and then my relative recent Traditional deeper conversion in response to my growing realization that since Vatican II's public announcement of Satan's control of Vatican. Such deeper Catechism into Traditional Catholic Theology was in defense of such destruction and re-construction of public shaping of Catholic Church into 'The Ape' version, and her soul-damnation It pushes.
The long & short of it was St. Thomas Aquinas' expressing how the Natural Law and later (earlier & later by his personal reference) Catholic Inspired revelations displays the answer to your question, mostly by defining Truth as something solid and rational.
Solid and rational that Modernists' insanity confused excuses and Satanic undermining that starting with the public spreading of René Descartes' propositions & 'philosophies' which broke from Natural Law, Catholic Theologies, and sanity, ...
.. Insanities which led to horror and Satanic Sickness throughout world, and today's broken rationality that makes mothers killing our babies, child mind and sexual mutilations, and more clear insanities as 'normal' and 'acceptable' from crib - if not required on pain of social and legal punishments, death.
I hope this is worth a serious consideration from you and those you have authority, influence, and interactions with, and visa-versa.
God Bless., Steve
